# How to fetch course price from moodle web service APIs

Tags: web-services, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am building mobile app that uses moodle web service APIs to fetch data, issue is i am not getting data for course price as well as start and end date for a particular enrolled course from the api response. Any help regarding this would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is web serivce functions to retrieve course price, start date and end date you have to create a custom web service to retrieve these values. Please note Moodle is not storing the course end date. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok got it, means no inbuilt moodle web service for the same. We need to create one to fetch from database tables, right?